# Is using Serialization a good idea?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, jvm

There are several risks regarding Serialization including incompatible changes. If incompatible changes occur in the classes being serialized then we can't de-serialize it even with static final long serialVersionUID field.

So, what's the alternatives of serialization ? XML ? If there's any alternative then is there at all any use of serialization in real world projects ?

Comment: In what context? Persistence? Networking?...

Comment: Using XML is just a different Serialization format.  Java supports XML serialization as well (built in)

Comment: You need to clarify what you understand by 'incompatible'. The Object Versioning section of the Object Serialization Specification specifies what is and is not a compatible class change. It is a lot more tolerant of class changes than you may think, as long as you specify a fixed `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: @EJP As I know,one of the incompatible changes is deletion of fields from the object.In that case you can't deserialize the object which was previously stored since the class file is changed.The older version of class file will be needed to get around that problem. But according to my conception, in case of xml, there's no such limitation.If any element is deleted then you have to just ignore the corresponding xml element while parsing. So, it'll not require the older version of class file like serialization.

Comment: @DebadyutiMaiti This comment proves my point 100%. You are completely mistaken about the effect of deleting a field. The object will deserialize, but with its default value. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678: "If a field is deleted in a class, the stream written will not contain its value. When the stream is read by an earlier class, the value of the field will be set to the default value because no value is available in the stream."

Comment: @EJP "The version control works great as long as the changes are compatible." - from http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/ . That's why I assumed it's not possible to deserialize if there's incompatible change.However,even if there's no problem in incompatible changes, if there's some cyclic reference in the object tree, then serialization process ,I think, wouldn't survive.I had used JAXB for XML creation,but it failed with lots of exception in that case. So,you see there's still one problem regarding serialization & JAXB.

Comment: @DebadyutiMaiti *Of course* there is a problem with incompatible changes. But deleting a field isn't an incompatible change for Object Serialization. As I said above, you need to inform yourself as to what is and isn't an incompatible change. At the moment you don't know. Object Serialization *also* handles cyclic graphs. You need to stop guessing about all this and read the Object Serialization Specification. And I haven't said a word here about JAXB.

Comment: @EJP Actually the link you provided in the previous comment [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678], contains "Deleting Fields" topic ,the 1st one under "Incompatible changes" topic. But you are saying "deleting a field isn't an incompatible change for Object Serialization". Then why is it under Incompatible changes on that link?

Comment: @DebadyutiMaiti It also says the object will be deserialzed etc as I quoted. Contrary to your statement above that it won't.

Comment: @EJP Then why it's termed as incompatible change? Incompatible changes means not being able to deserialize as the other types of incompatible changes suggests.But deleting field is not like that.

Comment: @DebadyutiMaiti It is an 'incompatible change' as described, i.e. certain values will take their default values. It is not an 'incompatible change' *that prevents the object from being deserialized,* as per your claim, which was, and remains, incorrect. I'm not responsible for why the Javadoc is organized and written the way it is, so asking me why is futile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there are alternatives to Java serialization: XML (as you've noted); JSON; protobuf; anything else that you'd care to use instead.

All of them will run some risk of incompatible changes.  I don't see that there's any magic in the other methods.  If you add a new attribute to an object, you've got to deal with "duck typing".  If you remove an attribute that's required, all methods will have problems.

Comment: The protocol changed to IIOP.

Answer (score 2):

you seem to be confusing serialization with data formats - it's probably best to separate them.

there are, broadly, three kinds of serialization:

1. **automated, comprehensive, low-level** - this is useful because it can be provided as a service and requires little effort to use.  but, by its nature, it is closely related to the internal format used in the language/program - if that changes then de-serialization will be "difficult".  typical examples are the "native" serialization provide by java and python; it's useful for short-term snapshots of program state.
2. **automated, restricted, medium-level** - typically used for communication/inter-operation.  this will not support all features of a language, probably allowing only simple data structures to be saved.  if that's sufficient then it's a useful middle ground as it can be automated but is independent of the language's internal format (but not, necessarily, of the program's details).  typical examples include protocol buffers, thrift, and json libraries (*not* json itself, which is a data format...); obviously, this is useful for comms and as ad-hoc data stores.
3. **"hand coded", high level** - this requires more work, and will probably save less information, but aims to extract the "important parts" in a way that is independent of the internal format used in the program (or language).  examples include docbook or open document (jaxb is rather nice in providing support for close-to-(1) by default, but allowing close-to-(3) with care); this is useful for long-term data archiving and is often associated with "official" specs.

separate from the above is the data format used to encode the serialized data.  i am sure you can implement all the above in xml; json tends to be used at (2).

anyway, to answer the question - (1) has the problems you note.  if (2) is sufficient, then it is a simple solution (but still suffers from some of the problems of (1) if data structures within the program change); otherwise you need to do the extra work implied by (3).

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your goal. If you're sending data between Java processes, the default Java serialization mechanism may work fine.

However, for storing data, particularly data which humans may want to look at or edit, the Java serialization mechanism is poorly suited.

There are a number of great XML-based java serialization libraries which I greatly prefer when human readable/editable output is required.

Two great ones are: [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) and [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/)